# google cloud analogy to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

Does google cloud have an analogous functionality to [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)?

In particular I would like compute resources to be opened up and jobs scheduled via [https events](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/invoke-aws-lambda-functions-over-https/).

I'm also interested in any other cloud hosting providers which have similar functionality.

Comment: I requested this feature here if you want to star it: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=253

Answer (score 4):

I just found out that there is something that looks interesting in the latest documentation of the SDK's command line tool `gcloud`.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/functions/

This sounds exciting.

**UPDATE:** Google just released some [official documentation of an alpha version of Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs). For now, functions can be written in Javascript using Node, and triggered by Pub/Sub, Cloud Storage, direct HTTP stimuli or manually for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Storage has Object Change Notification.  Only web hooks are currently supported at this time.

A client application can send a request to watch for a bucket's change notification events in order to be notified about changes to a bucket's objects.  After a notification channel is initiated, Google Cloud Storage notifies the application any time an object is added, updated, or removed from the bucket.

For example, when you add a new picture to a bucket, an application could be notified to create a thumbnail.

More info can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

Answer (score 2):

Regarding other providers that have similar functionality, check out [IronWorker](http://iron.io/worker). You can kick off IronWorker tasks via https endpoints using the [webhook endpoint](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/api/#queue_a_task_from_a_webhook) and you can run jobs on multiple clouds.  Here's a comparison of [Lambda vs IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/blog/2015/01/aws-lambda-vs-ironworker.html).

And yes, I work for Iron.io.

Comment: Awesome project; is there github code which shows minimal working examples on some cloud provider?

Comment: @NickThompson You can check out these examples: https://github.com/iron-io/dockerworker for various languages.

Answer (score 1):

Lately Google announced alpha release of [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) which supports http interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) and [Microsoft Azure functions](http://techcrunch.com/2016/03/31/microsoft-answers-aws-lambdas-event-triggered-serverless-apps-with-azure-functions/), they are both fairly new (Microsoft announced **Azure function** on March 31 2016)

Answer (score 0):

if you need Lambda with HTTP interface then look at [Nano Lambda](http://nano-lambda.com)
They can deploy to any cloud and on premise.